# Estrutura de erro JAVA

Tags: java

Alguém poderia me ajudar, exemplo no final do código tem a opção para a pessoa digitar SIM ou não, como faria para caso a pessoa digitasse outra palavra, aparecesse uma mensagem Falando que é Sim ou Não e voltasse a opção para a pessoa tentar novamente.

```
        valorTotalDoDia = valorTotalDoDia + valorCompra;
        System.out.println("♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎");
        System.out.println("O total do pedido deu: R$ " + valorCompra);
        System.out.println("♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎♦︎");
        z.clear();
        valorCompra = 0;
        System.out.println("Deseja finalizar o dia de trabalho ? ");
        fecharSistema = input.next("Sim para sair e Não para ficar");
        if (("Sim".equals(fecharSistema)) || ("sim".equals(fecharSistema))) {
            System.out.println("O valor total de vendas do dia é: R$ " + valorTotalDoDia);
            dia = false;
        } else {
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Já ouviu falar em laço de repetiçao? Ele é a resposta da sua pergunta.

Comment: AA Valeu, muito obrigado !!